# If space is expanding does the Plank unit also expend?

Tags: big-bang

There are three elements which I find their connection a bit confusing regarding the expanding universe.
1. The growing distance between the matter in the universe.
2. The actually expansion of space itself.
3. The planck unit.
So the simplest thing to understand is that the big bang was a big blast therefore all the matter that existed in this blast is now moving away from the center point of the blast. But on top of that it's also agreed that space itself is also expanding, but it's not clear exactly what this means. Is it just the space between the matter that is growing due to the growing distance? or, is it the outer limits of space that are growing? or, is the fabric of space itself is expanding? If the third one is the right one, then I don't understand how can light be an accurate measuring tool since it should also change its length according to the changes in the fabric of space.

Comment: The Planck's unit is just a combination of fundamental constants deeply connected to 1900-2017 experimental physics. It won't change.

Comment: @DanielC constancy of $c$, $\hbar$, $k_B$ and $k_C$ are all safe bets. If I had to bet, I'd also bet on the constancy of $G$, but only in the same way that the Higgs vacuum expectation value, and hence [$G_{\mathrm{Fermi}}$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermi%27s_interaction#Fermi_coupling_constant), is constant, at least until we get quantum gravity worked out.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: no. The [Planck units](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units) are all fixed in terms of Newton's constant, $G$, combined with others like: the speed of light, $c$, and Planck's constant $h$ (or $\hbar$). The "size of things" is set primarily by two constants, the mass of the electron $m_e$ and the fine structure constant, $\alpha$. To the best of our ability to measure them, none of these things are changing. We've made several searches for variations in the fine structure constant, in particular.

One way to understand the expansion of space-time is to think of it as adding a small repellent gravitational acceleration everywhere. Because the forces that hold atoms, and even are solar system, together dwarf this acceleration we didn't notice the expansion of space until we could measure the motion of things with sufficiently small forces between them (that is, galaxies).

Another way to understand it is to think about how we detected the effect in the first place. The process by which atoms produce light is extremely well studied in the discipline called spectroscopy, and it is an empirical fact from spectroscopy that low density gases of atoms absorb and emit light very strongly at particular wavelengths, and these wavelengths are determined by the electron mass, the fine structure constant, and quantum mechanics. More importantly, the pattern of wavelengths acts as a fingerprint that allows us to identify the atoms that caused them - that's how we first discovered that the sun is made of the same stuff as what we find here on Earth, and how helium was discovered before it was found on Earth.

The existence of these patterns are what allow us to say that the whole spectrum of light from a galaxy was stretched between when it was emitted in the pattern we know and when we detected it.

Importantly, none of these factors depends on the constancy of $G$. If it varied, the way it would affect things in the [Friedmann–Lemaître–Robertson–Walker](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric) metric would be by changing the way that the energy density, $\rho$, changed in time. To the best of our ability to make these determinations from observable data, $\rho$ behaves the way you'd expect it to if it were constructed from a cosmological constant $\Lambda$ which doesn't change with the expansion of space, ordinary "cold" dark matter with an energy density that drops as though the energy in a box expanding with the universe were conserved because it's all in mass, and the cosmic microwave background with energy in the same box that drops because all of the photons are being stretched with the box.

All that said, we're pretty sure there had to be a time when the electron's mass was $0$, but that was when the temperature of the universe was comparable to the mass of [Higgs boson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson), "long" before protons or neutrons were able to freeze out into distinct particles, so well before the cosmic microwave background was produced.

> So the simplest thing to understand is that the big bang was a big blast therefore all the matter that existed in this blast is now moving away from the center point of the blast.

This is an extremely common misconception. The big bang didn't happen anywhere, it happened everywhere. The most common analogy used is a good one - imagine we lived on the surface of an expanding balloon. Every person on that balloon would see everyone else moving away from them, but the expansion of the balloon didn't start at any one point on the balloon.

The next natural question would be, "What's space expanding into?" There are two good answers to this, "We don't know," and "Nothing, that we know of." See, the idea that space is static is so ingrained in our psyches that it's hard to understand that having a "bigger" static space in which our space is expanding isn't required. The mathematics works fine without it, so until there is some kind of observable evidence to support the existence of a static ur-spacetime in which ours is embedded, it's simpler to assume it doesn't exist.

If you want to read more, I suggest [Ned Wright's Cosmology Tutorial](http://www.astro.ucla.edu/~wright/cosmolog.htm). He does a good job of explaining a lot of what's going on at an introductory physics level, and addresses a lot of questions, misconceptions, and failed alternative models.